# MacPorts and HomeBrew: Can I install multiple packages from a file or list?

Tags: homebrew, macports

Surprised I couldn't find much information about this. I'm trying to create a list/file of all the ports and recipes I have installed and repopulate them on another Macbook. Is this possible without too much fuss?

ie. python pip has a feature where you can install from a requirements file that lists all the packages and their versions you want. `pip install -r requirementsfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [brewfile](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/brewfile-a-gemfile-but-for-homebrew) with Homebrew.

Comment: The Homebrew maintainers have indicated that this feature is deprecated and will not be maintained within Homebrew core in the future.

Comment: I'm glad it does still work. Is there any replacement or suggested procedure?

Comment: @TatjanaHeuser: I'd just do it with a shell script now.

Answer (score 4):

The [`port`](https://guide.macports.org/#using.port) program of [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) can read files of MacPorts commands, for example:

```sh
> cat cmdfile.txt
install git
install vim

> sudo port -F cmdfile.txt
--->  Computing dependencies for git
...
--->  Computing dependencies for vim
...
...
```

The option `-F` passes a "command file":

```sh
> port -h
Usage: port
        [-bcdfknNopqRstuvy] [-D portdir|portname] [-F cmdfile] action [actionflags]
        [[portname|pseudo-portname|port-url] [@version] [+-variant]... [option=value]...]...

"port help" or "man 1 port" for more information.
```

#### Running `portf`

It turns out that MacPorts also installs `portf`, which is a symbolic link to `port`:

```sh
> ls -l /opt/local/bin/portf
lr-xr-xr-x  1 root  admin  4 Jun 29 13:25 /opt/local/bin/portf -> port
```

and is equivalent to running `port -F`:

```sh
> sudo portf cmdfile.txt
--->  Computing dependencies for git
...
--->  Computing dependencies for vim
...
```

#### Specifying multiple package names per `install` command

Note that `port install` accepts multiple package names. Specifying multiple package names results in faster execution, because scanning of binaries for linking errors occurs upon completion of *each* `install` command (and consumes a nonnegligible amount of time). For example:

```sh
> cat cmdfile.txt
install git vim

> sudo port -F cmdfile.txt
--->  Computing dependencies for git
...
--->  Computing dependencies for vim
...
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
...
```

#### Installing packages listed in a requirements file

A quick way to run `port install` for a list of packages from a file is:

```sh
> cat macports_packages.txt
git
vim

> python -c '\
> with open("macports_packages.txt", "rt") as f:
>     text = f.read()
> print("install " + text.replace("\n", " "))' | sudo port
MacPorts 2.7.1
Entering shell mode... ("help" for help, "quit" to quit)
--->  Computing dependencies for git
...
--->  Computing dependencies for vim
...
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
...
```

### Details from MacPorts source code

#### Changelog

Quoting from the MacPorts changelog:

https://github.com/macports/macports-base/blob/9896034b1cf452ee905d61e9fcdee739d4112926/ChangeLog#L2487

> Release 1.3 (27-Jul-2006):

https://github.com/macports/macports-base/blob/9896034b1cf452ee905d61e9fcdee739d4112926/ChangeLog#L2584-L2586

> - Add new option -F  which specifies a command file to be
>   read and processed. Multiple such options may be given to provide
>   multiple command files. If filename is "-", then stdin is read.

https://github.com/macports/macports-base/blob/9896034b1cf452ee905d61e9fcdee739d4112926/ChangeLog#L2591-L2594

> - If port is invoked as portf, an -F is assumed as an implicit first
>   argument (so the real first argument is taken as a command file to
>   be processed). This should allow the use of a shebang line such as:
>   !/usr/bin/env portf

#### Code

The most relevant [Tcl code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) is:

https://github.com/macports/macports-base/blob/9896034b1cf452ee905d61e9fcdee739d4112926/src/port/port.tcl#L4628-L4633

```tcl
                    F {
                        # Name a command file to process
                        advance
                        if {[moreargs]} {
                            lappend ui_options(ports_commandfiles) [lookahead]
                        }
```

https://github.com/macports/macports-base/blob/9896034b1cf452ee905d61e9fcdee739d4112926/src/port/port.tcl#L5724-L5730

```tcl
# If we've been invoked as portf, then the first argument is assumed
# to be the name of a command file (i.e., there is an implicit -F
# before any arguments).
if {[moreargs] && $cmdname eq "portf"} {
    lappend ui_options(ports_commandfiles) [lookahead]
    advance
}
```

https://github.com/macports/macports-base/blob/9896034b1cf452ee905d61e9fcdee739d4112926/src/port/port.tcl#L5835

```tcl
        set exit_status [process_command_files $ui_options(ports_commandfiles)]
```

https://github.com/macports/macports-base/blob/9896034b1cf452ee905d61e9fcdee739d4112926/src/port/port.tcl#L4967-L4994

```tcl
proc process_command_files { filelist } {
    set exit_status 0

    # For each file in the command list, process commands
    # in the file
    foreach file $filelist {
        if {$file eq "-"} {
            set in stdin
        } else {
            if {[catch {set in [open $file]} result]} {
                fatal "Failed to open command file; $result"
            }
        }

        set exit_status [process_command_file $in]

        if {$in ne "stdin"} {
            close $in
        }

        # Exit on first failure unless -p was given
        if {$exit_status != 0 && ![macports::ui_isset ports_processall]} {
            return $exit_status
        }
    }

    return $exit_status
}
```

#### Searching

This information in the [repository `macports-base`](https://github.com/macports/macports-base) was located using [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), as follows:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:macports/macports-base.git
cd macports-base
ag -u 'command file'
```

Answer (score 3):

For MacPorts, you can grab a list of ports you manually installed using `port installed requested`. One way to get those installed again is writing a loop in bash; this might get tricky with variants, though.

Take a look at https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration which has basically the same requirements even though moving across boxes isn't covered (you can probably figure out where to switch the boxes). If you want to avoid the manual work, there's a script at the bottom.