# OSX - MACPORT - how to installation using multiple instances

Tags: macos, macports

**MACPORT**: whenever i try to install multiple packages in macport at once, i do get following.

```
sudo port install swi-prolog
Waiting for lock on /opt/local/var/macports/registry/.registry.lock
```

It asks me to wait until current package installation is completed. How can i run multiple instance of macport to install various packages parallely, so that i will not have to wait till one gets installed.
is there any workaround?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25751397/1959808

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently cannot run two macports commands to install ports at the same time. This feature has been [discussed](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.macports.user/30001), but was considered of too little use and too error-prone to implement. The registry lock is there specifically to *prevent* parallel port installations.

You can, however, specify several ports to install in one command (these will be installed one after the other, though):

```
sudo port install portA portB portC
```

Note that, to speed things up, ports in their default variant are usually available as binaries, i.e., do not need to be compiled on your system, and those that do need to be compiled will use parallel compilation where possible.